# <a4j:commandLink> not invoke action and actionListener

Tags: java, richfaces

I'm having a problem using a link that is inside a list.
The link does not invoke the action.
Has anyone experienced this and can you help me?

Follow below source code

```
rich:dataList id="dtList" rows="30" value="#{SegundaVia.listInsc}" var="list"

a4j:commandLink onclick="s2(#{list.inscnum});" oncomplete="openConfirmInsc();" 
action="#{getmanaged$FichaInscricaoSessionBean().teste}"  
value="#{list.contcargnum.contnum.userorgao} - #{list.inscnum} - #{list.contcargnum.cargnum.cargdescr}"

rich:dataList>
```

Comment: Good afternoon everyone!

I was able to make the link invoke the action,
I used the property ajaxSingle="true" on the button.

But my problem now is that I can not pass the item as a parameter of the action method

Example: a4j:commandLink action="#{SegundaVia.teste(list)}"

can anybody help me?

Bellow is the source code

rich:dataList id="dtList" rows="30" value="#{SegundaVia.listInsc}" var="list"

a4j:commandLink 
action="#{SegundaVia.teste(list)}"  
value="#{list.contcargnum.contnum.userorgao}

rich:dataList

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon everyone!

I was able to make the link invoke the action,
I used the property `ajaxSingle="true"` on the button.

But my problem now is that I can not pass the item as a parameter of the action method

Example: `a4j:commandLink action="#{SegundaVia.teste(list)}"`

can anybody help me?

Bellow is the source code

```
<rich:dataList id="dtList" rows="30" value="#{SegundaVia.listInsc}" var="list">

<a4j:commandLink action="#{SegundaVia.teste(list)}" value="#{list.contcargnum.contnum.userorgao}" />

</rich:dataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon everyone!
I finally managed to solve my problem,
Follow below solution

rich:dataList id="dtList" rows="30" value="#{SegundaVia.listInsc}" var="list"

a4j:commandLink ajaxSingle="true" onclick="s2(#{list.inscnum});" oncomplete="openConfirmInsc();" 
action="#{SegundaVia.prepararSegundaViaInscricao()}"
value="#{list.contcargnum.contnum.userorgao} - #{list.inscnum} - #{list.contcargnum.cargnum.cargdescr}" >

a4j:actionparam name="inscnum" value="#{list.inscnum}" 
assignTo="#{SegundaVia.inscnum}"

a4j:commandLink>

rich:dataList